# No more Sims in Simcity?

Tags: simcity-2013

I have come across something I've never seen before in simcity, no more people are populating my city. No one is taking residence in the newly built houses, no one is living in the high density residential areas, no one new is entering my city. I find it peculiar and wondered if it was my fault? If anyone has any ideas feel free to enlighten me

Comment: What are the stats of your city? I could try to answer it but I don't have that much information. Can you add more to your question?

Comment: Do you have any mods installed? Is the game paused? Did you try removing the road and dezoning the area and rezoning? Did you try to let the game run on high speed for a while and see if the problem fixed itself? As @snoozingnewt said, we need more info in order to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug back in 2013, where students that bussed to out-of-city schools would not return. The homes they left held their place as occupied. This would lead to city struggle as the homes would not obtain the education points from returning students.

The way to fix was to bulldoze the affected buildings and let new sims move in. This can be done gradually, a few buildings at a time.
 
If such a bug affected other kinds of residential sims, then the same fix may apply.